# beforeRouteLeave not triggering in some pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Problem: In the first/second pages after the user is redirected to my website, the beforeRouteLeave is not triggering when clicking the back button from the browser, but after the third page, works fine.

The flow is:
HomePage -> Redirected to another site -> Redirected back to my site -> FirstPage (not triggering on back button) -> SecondPage (not triggering on back button) -> ThirdPage (triggers on back button)

I want to warn the user when press the back button on the browser after the first page when it got back to my site.

BeforeRouteLeave on my Vue component:

```
 beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    if (!this.allowExitRoute) {
      // Alert user, if he continues, change the allowExitRoute to true
      next(false);
      return;
    }

    next();
  },
```

Method calling my secondPage

```
redirectToSecondPage() {
  this.allowExitRoute = true;
  this.$router.push('/secondPage');
},
```

Obs: When running history.pushState on console the beforeRouteLeave triggers, but running on mounted of my component, doesnt change anything

Comment: I guess that if you move to a website then back to your SPA, it will break the Vue router in some ways. Especially if using the back button functionality.

Comment: yes, i understand that will break on the FirstPage, since it was not called with $router.push, but on second it should work, since is the second and there is a history from the first one.